# embed iframe into blogger

Tags: html, iframe, embed, blogger

I'm having real problems embedding an iframe into my blogger site. I must confess I don't understand any html and have been attempting to copy bits of code I've found from around the web. I want to embed a friends blog into my own, and need to crop it so that it looks neater. His blog has a fixed width but dynamic height as he adds more posts. I've been defining the height of the iframe to be really large so as to make sure it will always fit in his posts no matter how large. The problem with this is that when you click a photo in his blog, it appears miles off the screen, and you have to scroll down loads to find it.

Here is my test blog - damianp1.blogspot.co.uk the page in question is test.

Here is the code I've used:

```
<style type="text/css">

.blog-pager, .footer, .post-footer, .feed-links, #Attribution1,.comments, .sidebar
{display:none !important;}
.main-inner .columns {width: 110%;padding-left:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;}

</style>
</b:if>
<style>]

</style>

<div class="post-outer" style="width:875px; color:#f6f6f6" >
<div id="outerdiv" style="width: 900px; overflow: hidden">
<iframe width="1300" style="position: relative; left: -205px; top: -34px" height="30000" 
src="http://wildlife-ramblings.blogspot.co.uk/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Is a solution to fit the iframe into a scroll-box so that any images clicked on would appear in the middle of this? How do I do this, or is there another solution?

Many thanks, Damian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to display his entire webpage? Why not just display an RSS feed of his website?

Otherwise you may want to set your iframe up like this, but if the website you are using the iframe on is larger than your site  in width or height you will need scrolling on or open the iframe just as large as the website contained in the iframe:

```
<iframe width="100%" frameborder="0" src="The blog URL Goes here" height="400"></iframe>
```

There is this handy little tool for adding blog iframes to blogger: http://www.makingdifferent.com/online-iframe-generator-tool-for-blogwebsite/

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried RSS feeds first, but we want to display the entire blog. I've sort of got it looking ok... http://damianp1.blogspot.co.uk/p/test_6572.html  but there's a pale blue box that hangs underneath the iframe that I'd like to get rid of - I can't find the id/class name for it. I'd love to be able to place the iframe into the original boxes of the template but can't find out how you do this. I'm doing a few html/css tutorial to try and get up to speed but it's quite hard!  Thanks, Damian.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to embed a google chart from a spreadsheet into a blogger post, and this worked nicely. Just needed to publish the chart and grab its url to replace `The blog URL Goes here` in your answer.